I want to disable previous months of selected month in multi-calendars in https://vue3datepicker.com/
I want to disable previous months of selected month in multi-calendars. If in first calendar suppose I've selected May month and when I open another calendar, month menu then it should show Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, and May should be disabled.
See Image Here

Vue3DatePicker answer
vue3datepicker documentation for disabled-dates prop.
<VueDatePicker v-model="date1" />
<VueDatePicker v-model="date2" :disabled-dates="disabledDates" />

import { useDate } from 'vuetify'
const date = useDate()

function disabledDates(val) {
  if (!date1.value) return
  const month = date1.value.getMonth() + 1 // zero-based
  return month === parseInt(date.toISO(val).split('-')[1])
}


Vuetify date picker answer
If you check the VDatePicker documentation you'll find exactly what you're looking for with the allowed-dates prop.  Given two v-date-pickers...
<v-date-picker v-model="date1" />
<v-date-picker v-model="date2" :allowed-dates="allowedDates" />

the function for what you want would test the selected month of the first date picker against the the date object that is passed in as a function parameter
function allowedDates(val) {
  if (!date1.value) return
  const month = date1.value.getMonth() + 1 // zero-based
  return month !== parseInt(date.toISO(val).split('-')[1])
}

working demo

Hello, @yoduh thanks for the answer. but, I'm not using vuetify I'm using https://vue3datepicker.com/.

I was working off the vuetify tag you included on the question, regardless the answer is almost the exact same.  vue3datepicker prop disabled-dates works the same way as vuetify's allowed-dates except the boolean result is the opposite, so for the logic all you have to do is change !== in the above code to ===. Please always consult API documentation for libraries you work with and go over every prop.  I am not familiar with vue3datepicker but all I've done to answer your question was consult the documentation

I've edited the answer to include the exact code solving the problem for both date pickers
